# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on using Spring Boot WebFlux Starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

I have created 2 Microservices with Spring Boot (version 1.5.1 RELEASE), Spring Cloud(Edgware.SR3), Spring Cloud Starter Config (version 1.4.3 RELEASE) and Netflix's Eureka naming server (Spring Cloud Starter Netflix Eureka Client/Server 1.4.4 RELEASE):

1. A Eureka Server (a service meant to register microservices)
2. A Eureka Client (a DB service meant for save/update operations)

Eureka Client is a simple Restful Service with a single`@PostMapping` annotated method which accepts a **sizeable object** as an argument (`@RequestBody MyObject object`).

Eureka client registers itself with Eureka server successfully.

Then with the help of **Spring Boot Webflux**, I try to access my Eureka Client with the help of class `WebClient` which is introduced in Spring 5 and is an improvisation on `AsyncRestTemplate` class. I do something like below :

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
reactor.core.publisher.Mono result = (Mono) webClient.post()
.uri("http://localhost:8080/eureka-client")
.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(//myComplexObject here))
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(String.class);

result.subscribe();
```

On debugging, I found that I get OOM exception after last line of above code.

```
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Full Stack Trace below :

```
[reactor-http-nio-4] WARN  io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor  - A task raised an exception. Task: reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler$$Lambda$401/11401686@10ae5a2

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:106)

                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:348)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.doWrite(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:291)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.drain(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:465)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.flush(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:191)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:802)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:814)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:794)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:831)

                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1051)

                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:300)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$then$0(HttpOperations.java:135)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.FutureMono.lambda$deferFuture$0(FutureMono.java:68)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.FutureMono$DeferredFutureMono.subscribe(FutureMono.java:134)

                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008)

                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167)

                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)

                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008)

                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:141)

                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60)

                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSourceFlux.subscribe(MonoSourceFlux.java:47)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380)

                at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpClientOperations.java:501)

                at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)

                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)

                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)

                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)

                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

                at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)

                at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent0.java:430)

                at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:596)

                at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:764)

                at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:740)

                at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:244)

                at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:214)

                at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:146)

                at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:324)

                at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:185)

                at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:176)

                at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:113)

                at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encode(HttpObjectEncoder.java:92)

                at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Encoder.encode(HttpClientCodec.java:167)

                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:88)

                ... 32 more
```

I have jackson library in my classpath and rely on spring to serialize my complex object while passing it to Restful service. I am not sure what may cause this. Any pointers please?

Comment: Maybe something goes wrong in the serialization of your "complex object". Could you add that to the question?

Comment: @SrThompson Its business code so I cant really share it but its a huge object with many object compositions (List, Map etc). So may be you are right in saying so. It may have caused due to large object size. However, I have enabled logging for netty classes so let me see if I can get some logs which prove this.

Comment: Check netty parameters like send and recv buffers, and jvm option -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=..., and make sure you have enough free memory.

Answer (score 0):

add this in java execution path

-Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true